# Is there any publically available job recommendation (person to job fit) dataset?

Tags: data-request, nlp

I want a dataset that contains resumes and job descriptions, and information about successful job applications for my research work. Is there any dataset available publically?

Answer (score 0):

[Job_Recommendation analysis](https://www.kaggle.com/kandij/job-recommendation-datasets?select=job_data.csv)

A recommendation engine is build using NLTK helping the applicants to choose their preferred job based on their application. You will learn how lemmatizer, stemming and vectorization are used to process the data and have a better output.

The dataset was found on Kaggle, with a total of 8,653 entries of applicant experiences and 80,000 job listings. Note that these applicant experiences are not specifically for any of the job listings.

An article on [How to Build a Resume Recommender like the Applicant Tracking System (ATS)](https://towardsdatascience.com/resume-screening-tool-resume-recommendation-engine-in-a-nutshell-53fcf6e6559b)

---

https://github.com/JAIJANYANI/Automated-Resume-Screening-System

---